# What is the concept of phase congruency?

Tags: signal-processing, image-processing

I am beginner in signal processing. I am studying the importance of phase in signals. I want to know about **Phase
Congruency**, but there is very little
information available on internet.

So can anybody simplify the concept of
phase congruency and its physical
significance?

Comment: Might this be better at [dsp.SE]?